# Stop Android Service after some time?

Tags: android, service

I have a  background service in my app which is started by Widget. When User Starts service it's going to run until user stop it. And that can drain battery a lot if user forgets to stop it.
I want to add some safety to switch. To stop service after some time like 5 or 10 minutes. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a Handler to stop service after specific delay:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 1: {
                stopSelf();
            }break;
        }
    }
}
```

And provide your delay below:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 300000);//add your delay here
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that unless your `Service` is actively processing something or holding a wakelock it is not consuming more battery.  A `Service` can be in the "running" state but not doing anything.  The Android framework is event driven, so unless you are still executing an `onStartCommand()` or a background thread you spawned then you are not consuming CPU or battery.  That being said, if you do need to kill off your `Service` after a specific amount of time, use an alarm set via the `AlarmManager`.